# Unknown column in field list explenation

Tags: mysql

When I go to run this query I am presented with the following error.

```
SELECT users.name
FROM users as u

Error
SQL query: 
SELECT users.name
FROM users as u LIMIT 0, 25
MySQL said: 
#1054 - Unknown column 'users.name' in 'field list'
```

Yet if I reference the columns I'd like to select by the table alias then the query works as expected

```
SELECT u.name
FROM users as u
```

Can anyone explain to me why it works this way? Is it the expected behavior?

Comment: Yes - This is expected behavior. `users as u` renames the table within the query. With the rename, `users` is unknown so `users.name` is an error..

Comment: You've given the `users` table an alias (a new temporary name) when you write `FROM users as u`, which means that you now need to reference it using that temporary name. This is standard behavior for most (if not all) SQL DBMSs.

Comment: Okay, thank you guys. I assumed I would still be able to reference the columns by their original names before I wrote the line that aliased the table just not those after.

Comment: Think about it . What if you had two instances of your users table, both aliased. To which table would `users` then refer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The users table is renamed so you must access it by it's new name. You may not continue to use its previous name in your column selections.